# Get data from grid row using vaadin

Tags: java, jpa, vaadin

I am making a CRUD application using vaadin
I have a grid with an object Person (id, name, age)
I made an "edit" button next to each row, but how do I get the Person value of that row when I press the button?

```
 grid.addComponentColumn(e -> new Button("Edit"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `e` variable on your example is the grid item, i.e. the Person instance. If you expand the callback to a block to add a listener to the button rather than only creating one, then you can directly reference the item in that listener.

Code for that could thus be something along these lines (assuming there's a `getName()` method in `Person`):

```
grid.addComponentColumn(person -> {
  Button button = new Button("Edit");
  button.addClickListener(event -> Notification.show("Editing " + person.getName()));
  return button;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you give an example code please?

Comment: I edited the response to include a simple code example